# Python change every n-th pixel of an image on x and y axis to a different color

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

As the title says, I have to take an image and write code that colors in every n-th pixel on x axis and every n-th pixel on y axis.

I tried using coloring every pixel manually but it will take too much  time because image is 500x500 and it will take eternity to change every pixel based on its number on x and y axis.

Comment: How do you load the image? If it's an array, setting every `n`th value is as easy as setting the correct slice to that value.

Comment: Pranav is correct. Load it as an array and this should be easy

Comment: It isnt array i have to edit the image it is in jupyter notebook the arrays will not work because i have to change the color of every second pixel on the x axis and every third on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think (@PranavHosangadi) and (@Mike L) are correct.
I don't see how it is possible without a loop. But you can use the loop in this way by skipping the pixels and not iterate over each position.

This is an example to change the value at a location by skipping 2 rows and 2 columns.

```
import numpy as np

img = np.ones((10,10))
print(f"Array 1: \n {img}")
w, h = img.shape

for i in range(0, h, 3):
    #if i % 2 == 0:
    img[i,i] = 0

print(f"Array 2: \n {img}")
```

Comment: I need to change a color to black for a 500x500x picture for every 2-nd value of the x axis and every 3-rd for y axis. I had this code it doesnt work from                                 PIL import Image

picture_resized = picture.resize( (500,500) )

im = np.array(Image.open('Lenna.png').convert('RGB'))

Image.fromarray(im).save('result.png')

im[0::2,0::2] = [0,0,0] im[0::3,0::3] = [0,0,0]

%matplotlib notebook plt.imshow(picture_resized)